# aws parameter key not updating in elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ssm

I am using a parameter key in my elastic beanstalk environment under **Environment properties** by `{{resolve:ssm:production-MAILCHIMP_API_KEY:1}}` as the value. On environment creation this works fine but once I update the value in the parameter store it does not reflect into my environment. I tried restarting the app but still it picks up the old value. So I had to paste it in normally without using parameter key and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only **passing version 1** of your SSM parameter:

```
{{resolve:ssm:production-MAILCHIMP_API_KEY:1}}
```

You **can't edit SSM parameters**, you only create their newer versions. Thus, if you update (i.e. create new version) of your SSM parameter, you have to updated your settings in EB, to use version 2,3 and so on:

```
{{resolve:ssm:production-MAILCHIMP_API_KEY:2}}
```

This will updated your environment and you get new value passed to the EB instance(s).